# Arraylist of Conditions?

Tags: java, xml, arraylist

I have an array list of expressions and an array list of files
I am making a filter for these files; the filter will also be Arraylist ->

Let's say I have an array list with 4 files [file, file, file, file] text files for example
and I have these 3 expressions / conditions:

[X, O, Z]

In order to move one of the files into the filter array list, the 3 conditions must be validated in the file

```
ArrayList<String> XpathExpression= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<File> FilterdFiles= new ArrayList<File>();
File folder = new File("Path for many files");
        File[] files = folder.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            
            if(file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                
                //Parser here

                /*******Get attribute values******/
                
                for(String xpathExp: XpathExpression) {

                    if(what I have to write in the if statment to check that the three conditions are valid for the current file so i can add it to the FilterdFiles.) {
                        
                        FilterdFiles.add(file);
                    
                        }
                    
                    else
                        
                    continue;
                        }
```

WHAT I have to write in the if statment to check that the three conditions are valid for the current file so i can add it to the FilterdFiles.

Comment: Your expressions are XPATH expressions? Please look into https://www.baeldung.com/java-xpath and see how to (Retrive a specific node using xpath expression)

IF node != null validates one of your expressions.  Start simple (Validate 1 expression), then look into the other 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give you a solution based on your code because it doesn't contain enough information.  But I can give you an example that should help you solve your problem.

The code below will add strings from a list that contains all strings in another array.  I use the flag matched to keep track of matches.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] files = {"cat and dog", "dog", "fish dog cat", "apple", "peach"};
        String[] expressions = {"dog", "cat"};
        ArrayList<String> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for(String f: files){
            boolean matched = true;
            for(String e: expressions){
                if (!f.contains(e)) { 
                    matched = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (matched)  filtered.add(f);
        }
        
        System.out.println(filtered);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[cat and dog, fish dog cat]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write another validate method like this if all the conditions must match:

```
private boolean validate(File file, ArrayList<String> XpathExpression){
   for(String xpathExp: XpathExpression){
       boolean validateResult = validate file with xpathExp;
       if(validateResult != true){
           return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

then add file to filter array list if `validate(file, XpathExpression)` return true.
Or validate if any xpathExp matches:

```
private boolean validate(File file, ArrayList<String> XpathExpression){
   for(String xpathExp: XpathExpression){
       boolean validateResult = validate file with xpathExp;
       if(validateResult == true){
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```